# Convert decimal number to k-bit binary

Tags: c++

I’m trying to implement a function like

```
auto Solution(int num, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

For example, Solution(5, 6) return vector = {0,0,0,1,0,1}.  Solution(4, 3) return vector = {1,0,0}.
I'm new c++ beginner and don't know how to do it

Comment: *"I’m trying to implement a function ..."* What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for(--k; k >= 0; --k) result.push_back(!!(num & (1 << k)));` should do the trick

Comment: Appreciate Bystander. It's a cool trick

Answer (score 0):

For the first of all I advice you to use **std::bitset** to handle bits. And if you need to store each bit separately in vector use smallest integer size (e.g. **int8_t**).

And I think even in my example usage of **std::vector** is excessively. You can access **bits** object directly like a regular array of **0** and **1** values. In C++ you don't really need bitwise operations to separate integer for individual bits.

```
auto Solution(int num, int k)
{
    std::bitset<sizeof(num) * 8> bits(num);
    std::vector<int8_t> result(k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        result[i] = bits[i];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: FYI `sizeof(num)` will not be enough to hold all bits of `num`. Eg, on x64 `sizeof(num)` will be 8 at most.

Comment: Yes you right. I forgot to multiply by 8. Fixed it.

Comment: Two more things to make your code portable: (1) `std::int8_t` is not guaranteed to exist on all platforms. It's better to use `int`. (2) Size of `char` may not always be 8 bits either, so it's better to multiply by `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8`. HTH